# Display result of picked option on same page

Tags: php, html

I am new to php. I will try to explain as good as i can, and if you need more info just let me know.

I have a index.php like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'connection.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

?>

<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location 
= this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="">Velg campus</option>
<option value="showSchool.php?id=1">School 1</option>
<option value="showSchool.php?id=2">School 2</option>
<option value="showSchool.php?id=3">School 3</option>
</select>
```

I have a class, School.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

class School extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [ 'id', 'name', 'adress', 'picture'];

 }
```

And i have a showSchool.php like this:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

$school = School::find($_GET['id']);

?>

<h1 class="name"><?= $school['name'] ?></h1>
<p class="adress"><?= $school['adress'] ?></p>
<img src="<?= $school['picture'] ?>" height="200">
```

I am using the Eloquent library for SQL connection, which is placed in connection.php:

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$capsule = new Capsule();

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 3305,
    'database' => 'school',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'collation' => 'latin1_swedish_ci'

]);

$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

So to sum what i have up, in words:

- When i click one of the options, like the one who says "School 1", it sends me to the page "showSchool.php?=id1" which then displays a name, an adress, and a picture of the school.

What i have absolutely no clue how, but i really want to achieve is:

- The school information (which is displayed in showSchool.php), should be displayed on the same page as the drop down menu/under the drop down menu, in other words also at index.php.
- Also, in the drop down menu, you can see i assign the values to i.e "showSchool.php?id=1". Is there any other way to handle this, say in example if a new row (school) will be added to the database, the dropdown menu will always have the correct options? Or is the easiest way to just update the options manually?

I think the last question might correlate with the first question, since displaying the school information on the same page will probably change the entire structure of my dropdown menu anyways.

Ok, i think i have explained well enough.

I am grateful for any answer i might get!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instantiation of the class does not match the class name defined in School.php (Skole vs. School).

Replace your hardcoded school links using a query out to your School class. It should query your database and return all the school IDs and names e.g. to build a dynamic set that now points to your index.php page.

```
$schoolList = School::all();
$links = '';
foreach($schoolList as $schoolID)
{
    $links .= '<option value="index.php?id=' . $schoolID['id'] . '">' . $schoolID['name'] . '</option>'.PHP_EOL;
}

?>
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location= this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="">Velg campus</option>
<? echo $links; ?>
</select>

<?
//Move your showSchool.php code into an if block on index.php

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    include 'connection.php';

    $school = School::find($_GET['id']);

?>

<h1 class="name"><?= $school['name'] ?></h1>
<p class="adress"><?= $school['adress'] ?></p>
<img src="<?= $school['picture'] ?>" height="200">
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, i catch your drift, and i am not expecting any finished solution, but your code displays this error: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp64\www\Eksamen\index.php on line 11

Comment: It's missing a ; at the end of "PHP_EOL"

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks alot dude, appreciate it.

Comment: When i first have made a post for this, i might aswell ask one more question. When i run index.php without any id for parameter (not choosing anything from the drop down menu), i do not suprisingly get an error. Do you know how i can fix this? So that the index without a parameter is just a blank page?

Comment: Are you getting the dropdown? Or are you getting an error?

Comment: When i pick an option in the dropdown (and the url bar shows i.e http://localhost/index.php?id=3), it all works fine. But when i try to enter index.php with no id specified (http://localhost/index.php), it obviously wont show any school because an id is not specified in the url. I have an idea how to fix it, by adding a new row in the DB with name "Pick a school", and an if statement which does so that if the name column of the row is "Pick a school", a blank echo will be issued, else the school information will be echo'ed. There must be a better way than adding an empty field in the DB though

Comment: add an "else" block at the end of the showSchool code e.g. `else{ echo "<h2>No School Selected</h2>Please choose a school above to view its details...";}`